# Which langugage extensions are implied by Haskell2010 in ghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I don't know why I'm having trouble finding the docs for this, but which extensions are implied by:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
```

I'm mostly just concerned with how ghc handles this, but I assume this is part of the standard.

Comment: `Haskell2010` does not imply `MultiParamTypeClasses`.

Comment: @ReidBarton can you elaborate? (see my edit). Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Your example demonstrates that `class Foo a b` is *not* accepted without strictly enabling `MultiParamTypeClasses`, even when `Haskell2010` is enabled (which is the default for ghci).

Comment: Sorry I'm just tired, and was being stupid! (unedited)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the very last section of the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch12.html#x19-19100012.3), I believe this is what you are looking for (emphasis mine):

> Haskell 2010 implementations that support the LANGUAGE pragma are
>   required to support
>
> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
> ```
>
> Those implementations are also encouraged to support the following
>   named language features:
>
> ```
> PatternGuards, NoNPlusKPatterns, RelaxedPolyRec,  
> EmptyDataDecls, ForeignFunctionInterface
> ```
>
> **These are the named language extensions supported by some pre-Haskell**
>   **2010 implementations, that have been integrated into this report.**

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that answers the question. I updated my question to perhaps be more clear.

Comment: @jberryman As another commentor noted, Haskell2010 does not imply MultiParamTypeClasses. `echo "class C a b" > test.hs && ghc -XHaskell2010 test.hs` results in an error.

Comment: Ugh sorry I wasn't reading what I was myself typing. nevermind